# How to find the dependency that links to stdlibc++?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently working on an iOS project that are running properly on Xcode 9.4.1.

Since apple will force all of the submitted  app to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later ( which are included in Xcode 10.1 or later), therefore, I plan to upgrade my current project so it can be used on Xcode 10.1.

However, I got this [stdlibc++ headers not found error..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkams.png)

```
Showing All Messages
ProcessPCH++ /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/5421139595203421822/TV_Prefix.pch.gch /Users/nm/Desktop/temp\ v2\ code/iphone/from\ bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone/src/TV_Prefix.pch normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target: TV_iPhone)
    cd /Users/nm/Desktop/temp\ v2\ code/iphone/from\ bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone
    /Applications/Xcode10.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode10.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-move -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-range-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -index-store-path /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode10.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Applications/Xcode10.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -I/Users/nm/Desktop/temp\ v2\ code/iphone/from\ bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone/opensource/Curl -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nm/Desktop/temp\ v2\ code/iphone/from\ bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone -F/Users/nm/Desktop/temp\ v2\ code/iphone/from\ bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone -c /Users/nm/Desktop/temp\ v2\ code/iphone/from\ bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone/src/TV_Prefix.pch -MD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/5421139595203421822/TV_Prefix.pch.d -iquote /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/Media\ Everywhere-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode10.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Applications/Xcode10.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml -I/Users/nm/Desktop/temp\ v2\ code/iphone/from\ bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone/opensource/Curl -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/tv.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TV_iPhone.build/DerivedSources -o /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/5421139595203421822/TV_Prefix.pch.gch --serialize-diagnostics /Users/nm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tv-emcztnhcvllybhaitrhobnyjdasf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/5421139595203421822/TV_Prefix.pch.dia
error: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Werror,-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
1 error generated.
```

I know that libstdc++ is not supported on Xcode 10 and I plan to do the necassary changes.

Since this project has not been developed initially by me and the people related to it has been out of reach, **is there any way that I can do to find which file inside the project has dependency on the stdlibc++**? Plus, my project doesn't used any cocoapods and fully developed on objective-c

Thank you for your assistance in advance. ^_^

Comment: What file was being compiled when that error was produced? Copy the whole output from that step, verbatim, and edit your question to paste it in there (marked as code). You can right-click or Control-click on the error line in the build log to get a copy command.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @KenThomases

Answer (score 0):

It's compiling the precompiled header: /Users/nm/Desktop/temp v2 code/iphone/from bitbucket/v2-ios-iphone/src/TV_Prefix.pch

It's compiling it as a C++ header. I'm not sure if that's because it's marked as a C++ file in the file's settings or if it does that whenever there's any C++ source file in the project.